# Programmatical equivalent to UIViewController's "Resize View From NIB" property

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

What is the programmatical equivalent to `UIViewController`'s *Resize View From NIB* when editing a storyboard in Xcode's Interface Builder?

I want to set this to no for a view controller that uses a *xib* file instead of a storyboard.

[image: Resize View From NIB]

Comment: What's the behavior you're looking for? Are you wanting to use AutoLayout? There are resources on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method in `UIViewController` that is meant to be mapped to that IB property. However, since it affects the size and position of the top-level view in relation to the status bar, the programmatic equivalent would probably be the following, if the status bar is visible:

```
int statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, statusBarHeight, viewFrame.size.width, viewFrame.size.height - statusBarHeight);
```